# Mysterious user parameter appearing in body of request (Swift/Auth0/Rails/Neo4j)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, jwt, auth0

I have an xCode project that has a UserViewModel that sends a signup/login request to Auth0 to register a user with their email and password.  When the user successfully signs up, they are redirected back to my application and are prompted to select a username and a bio and upload a profile picture.  This request is then sent to a user service in Rails where the user node should be stored in a separate neo4j database.  I set up the Rails project to skip active record setup and be in API only mode.  I am using the gems 'neo4j', 'rack-cors', and 'jwt'.

Here is the function that the client sends to the server to update the user profile:

```
func updateProfile(username: String, bio: String, picture: UIImage?) {
        guard let url = URL(string: Constants.Services.User.baseURL + Constants.Services.User.updateProfileEndpoint) else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }
    
        let pictureUrl = "" // Placeholder
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("Bearer \(self.accessToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        
        let body = ["username": username, "bio": bio, "profile_picture": pictureUrl]
        request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body, options: [])
        
        print(body)
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error: \(error)")
            } else if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200 {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.profileComplete = true
                }
            } else {
                print("Failed to update profile")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
```

The output of print(body) looks correct - `["profile_picture": "", "bio": "testbio", "username": "testuser"]`

However, in the terminal output for my user service I am getting this: `Parameters: {"username"=>"testuser", "profile_picture"=>"", "bio"=>"testbio", "user"=>{"username"=>"testuser", "bio"=>"testbio", "profile_picture"=>""}}`

In that same output, I am getting RuntimeError (No session defined!): app/controllers/application_controller.rb:7:in 'neo4j_session'.

Here is the code for my Rails Project, firstly the application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API

before_action :neo4j_session

private

def neo4j_session
  @neo4j_session ||= Neo4j::ActiveBase.current_session
end
end
```

And the UsersController:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_request!, except: [:create]
  
  def create
    puts params
      @user = User.new(user_params)
      if @user.save
          render json: @user, status: :created
      else
          render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
      end
  end
  
  private
  
  def user_params
      params.permit(:username, :bio, :profile_picture)
  end
  
  def authenticate_request!
      header = request.headers['Authorization']
      header = header.split(' ').last if header
      begin
          @decoded = JWT.decode(header, '<My Auth0 Secret>', true, { algorithm: 'HS256' })[0]
      rescue JWT::DecodeError => e
          nil
      end
  end
end
```

And the User Model:

```
class User 
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  property :username, type: String
  property :bio, type: String
  property :profile_picture, type: String

  validates_uniqueness_of :username

  def self.from_token_payload(payload)
    find_by(username: payload['username'])
  end

end
```

And my neo4j.yml file:

```
development:
type: bolt
url: bolt://localhost:7687
username: neo4j
password: <My password> 
encrypted: false
```

I do not see anywhere in my client code that would edit the request body, since all functionality is in the UserViewModel and in that updateprofile function.

Here are the signup and login functions in the UserViewModel that communicate with Auth0:

```
func login() {
        Auth0.webAuth().start { result in
            switch result {
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Failed with: \(error)")
            case .success(let credentials):
                self.authenticated = true
                self.userProfile = Profile.from(credentials.idToken)
                self.accessToken = credentials.accessToken
            }
        }
    }
    
    func logout() {
        Auth0.webAuth().clearSession() { result in
            switch result {
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Failed with: \(error)")
            case .success:
                self.authenticated = false
                self.userProfile = Profile.empty
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: So you're seeing twice the body in your server part, right? So the issue seems to be in the server part since that body would be invalid (same keys multiples times in an object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is the [ActionController::ParamsWrapper](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.4.2/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html)

> Wraps the parameters hash into a nested hash. This will allow clients to submit requests without having to specify any root elements.
>
> **This functionality is enabled by default for JSON**...
>
> ...instead of having to send JSON parameters like this:
>
> `{"user": {"name": "Konata"}}`
>
> You can send parameters like this:
>
> `{"name": "Konata"}`
>
> And it will be wrapped into a nested hash with the key name matching the controller's name. For example, if you're posting to UsersController, your new params hash will look like this:
>
> `{"name" => "Konata", "user" => {"name" => "Konata"}}`
>
> To disable this functionality for a controller:
>
> ```
> class UsersController < ApplicationController
>   wrap_parameters false
> end
> ```